# Problems with closing TcpClient and NetworkStream

Tags: c#, tcpclient, networkstream

currently I am working on a simple client server chat program (wanted to get into client server communication things in C#). It works so far except for disconnecting properly from the server.

On the client I use this code here to close the connection:

```
client.Client.Disconnect(false); // client is the TcpClient
client.Close();
```

On the server there is a threaded loop waiting for messages from the client:

```
private void StartChat()
{
    int requestCount = 0;
    byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
    string dataFromClient = null;
    string rCount = null;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            requestCount++;

            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            int bufferSize = (int)tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize;
            if (bufferSize > bytesFrom.Length)
            {
                bufferSize = bytesFrom.Length;
            }

            stream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bufferSize);
            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFrom);
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
            rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);

            string message = client.Name + " says: " + dataFromClient;
            program.Broadcast(message);

        }
        catch(Exception ex) when (ex is ObjectDisposedException || ex is InvalidOperationException || ex is System.IO.IOException)
        { 
            program.UserDisconnected(client);
            break;
        }
        catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            break;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            break;
        }
    }
```

If the client disconnects with the code shown above the function is fetching the stream all the time and producing such an output:

`\0\0\0\0\0\0\0 [and so on]`

In this case the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` will be thrown because there is no index of `$`. I added a `break` to avoid and endless execution of the loop.

Surprisingly the `ObjectDisposedException` will not be thrown. Also the `System.IO.IOException` will not be thrown however it should because the stream was closed so the connection has been refused.

If I just close the client application which is connected to the server the server doesn't stops the loop, it just waits for a stream which will never come because the client disconnected.

So how could I detect if the client is disconnected or not reachable any more? And is the way I am closing the client connection a proper way to close a connection?

Thanks for your help!

Update:

```
private void StartChat()
{
    int requestCount = 0;
    byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
    string dataFromClient = null;
    string rCount = null;

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            requestCount++;

            NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            stream.ReadTimeout = 4000;

            int bufferSize = (int)tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize;
            if (bufferSize > bytesFrom.Length)
            {
                bufferSize = bytesFrom.Length;
            }


            // Wait for a client message. If no message is recieved within the ReadTimeout a IOException will be thrown
            try
            {
                int bytesRead = stream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bufferSize);
                stream.Flush();

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    throw new System.IO.IOException("Connection seems to be refused or closed.");
                }
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException)
            {
                byte[] ping = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("%");
                stream.WriteTimeout = 1;

                stream.Write(ping, 0, ping.Length);
                continue;
            }


            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
            dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
            rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount);

            string message = client.Name + " says: " + dataFromClient;
            program.Broadcast(message);

        }
        catch(Exception ex) when (ex is ObjectDisposedException || ex is InvalidOperationException || ex is System.IO.IOException)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            program.UserDisconnected(client);
            break;
        }
        catch(ArgumentOutOfRangeException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the return value of `stream.Read` - it returns the number of bytes *actually* read.

This will be 0 when the client has disconnected, and when it does read data, the number of bytes read are often less than the buffer size.

```
int bytes = stream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bufferSize);
if (bytes == 0)
{
    // client has disconnected
    break;
}

dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytesFrom, 0, bytes);
```

In response to your recent comment, three things can happen when a client terminates its connection:

- The client closes the connection correctly, and you receive 0 bytes
- Something detectable happened, causing an exception
- The client is "gone" but no signal is sent to your end

In this last situation the server will still act as if there is an active connection, until it tries to send data, which would obviously fail. This is why many protocols work with a connection timeout and/or a keep-alive mechanism.

Comment: Does this means that you can't detect if the client has gone away? Looking at the docu it should throw an ObjectDispoedException or at least an IOException because it can't read anymore from it

Comment: A _graceful_ disconnect is not an exceptional case, and is detected by `stream.Read()` returning 0. You should indeed have an exception handler, but I doubt `ObjectDisposedException` will be thrown unless you dispose it yourself and then try to use it.

Comment: You're right, DisposedException won't be thrown unless this object is still there and not deleted by garbage collector or manually disposed. However, huge thanks, this worked! I will accept your answer asap. 

Edit: If I close the client the loop won't end and will stay until the server application was closed. How could I fix this?

Comment: @chris579 Responded to that last question in my answer.

Comment: The first two cases are already handled but the third is causing problems atm. I updated how the code looks like now. The second stream write succeeds although the client is already gone. I don't really know how to fix this behaviour. I already tried to send a small package to the client which will send a small package back but even if the client is gone the server can read from the stream and gets a package which couldn't be send because the client was already gone.

Answer (score 1):

int bytesRead = stream.Read(...);   if (bytesRead == 0) // client disconneted

Comment: Well you're to slow. Look at the answer above ;)

Comment: ya...I know there are enough developers around here, maybe the site could let a person know when there is a new comment/answer...and fix the pagination while they're at it : p

Comment: Yeah :) There is still one issue pending just look at my comment in the first answer. Maybe you can help me with this ;)

Comment: I looked, I don't see the issue. (?)

Comment: Well If I close the client without doing a clean disconnect the client won't timeout meaning the client loop posted in my question will wait endless for the client to send a message.

Comment: I can't think how to put it eloquently, so, that's just the nature of the beast..you're telling it to wait until it receives a msg, and dammit it will :p You can probably set the 'read timeout' to be shorter - there is no* way to detect if one of the peers simply 'walks away.' ..another option is sending a 'heartbeat', to verify it's still there (which will timeout/fail if it's not).

Comment: Mhh, I will set a timeout (something like all 4 seconds) and will then send an empty package to the client to get a returned package. If this package is not coming back in 4 seconds it will stop the client execution.
Thanks for the help!